# Getting email notification when jobs are created under user_schema rather than sys?

Tags: oracle, oracle-12c, jobs

I log in as sys and set the smtp for scheduler:

```
BEGIN
  DBMS_SCHEDULER.set_scheduler_attribute('email_server', '10.1.1.15');
  DBMS_SCHEDULER.set_scheduler_attribute('email_sender', 'user@compny.com');
END;
/
```

Then create a job under user schema:

```
BEGIN
  DBMS_SCHEDULER.create_job (
    job_name        => 'user.daksh_job',
    job_type        => 'PLSQL_BLOCK',
    job_action      => 'BEGIN NULL; END;',
    start_date      => SYSTIMESTAMP,
    repeat_interval => 'freq=minutely; bysecond=0',
    end_date        => SYSTIMESTAMP + 1/24,
    enabled         => TRUE);
END;
/
```

and configure the email notification:

```
BEGIN
 DBMS_SCHEDULER.add_job_email_notification (
  job_name   =>   'user.daksh_job',
  recipients =>  'dasharath.dixit@suddath.com',
  subject => 'Scheduler Job Notification : %daksh%.%daksh_job%-%event_type%',
  events     =>  'job_started, job_succeeded');
END;
/
```

I am not getting any email. If I create the job under sys schema I am getting an email.

I did not give any permission to user to send an email. It is Oracle 12.1. I just set the scheduler attribute under that user schema. Job is running successfully every time, but email is not coming.

I think we don't have to configure the utl_mail for during schedule a job only

```
BEGIN
  DBMS_SCHEDULER.set_scheduler_attribute('email_server', '10.1.1.15');
  DBMS_SCHEDULER.set_scheduler_attribute('email_sender', 'user@compny.com');
END;
/
```

Comment: I see that you said you can get email if sent from the SYS schema but not your application schema.  So that proves that utl_mail is fundamentally installed and working.  Further, it indicates a permissions issue.  Two things to check: does the apps schema have EXECUTE on UTL_MAIL, and is the network acl set up correctly?

Comment: You probably should check metalink, there are few bugs associated with this functionality. you may need to raise a service request with Oracle.

Comment: Does the job run when executed under the user ID, and you just do not receive the emails? If you are the job owner, you should be able to successfully invoke the `DBMS_SCHEDULER.add_job_email_notification` procedure.